# How to find a specific word between two sentences in a text file

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose this is my text file info.txt :

```
My Name is 
Joe
My Age is 
25
My phone is
Nokia
```

Is there an efficient way to return 25 with Javascript (Knowing that it comes in the line after"My Age is" ?

I'm using vanilla Javascript and FileReader

Comment: If that sentence is always like that you can use a RegExp.

Comment: @Dormilich can you give an example for this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use RegEx for that:

```
let matches = str.match(/My Age Is\s?\n([0-9]+)/i)
let age = matches[1];
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tee3y172/

And, here's how that breaks down:

- My Age Is - Match this string
- \s? - possibly followed by a space (in your example it is followed by a space)
- \n - Followed by a new line
- `([0-9]+)` - Followed by any series of numbers (you could also use `\d+`) and group them (that's what the perenthesis are for).
- i - ignore case

The grouping then allows you to capture the text you want at index 1 (`matches[1]`).

For matching anything on the line after "My age is" you can use the `(.*)` which will match anything except a newline:

```
let matches = str.match(/My Age Is\s?\n(.*)/i)
let age = (!!matches) ? matches[1] : 'No match';
```

Here's the JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/spadLeqw/

Comment: In that case you can just use `(.*)` which matches anything except a newline:  `/My Age Is\s?\n(.*)/i`. Here;s the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5utupaob/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use a [`regular expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match the digits that come after specific words

```js
const str = 'My Name is\nJoe\nMy Age is \n25\nMy phone is\nNokia';
const match = str.match(/My Age is \n(\d+)/)[1];
console.log(match);
```

Additional resources

- [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: what should I use instead of the d+ if the 25 could be "twenty five" too?

Answer (score 1):

```
txt.split(/Age.+/)[1].match(/.+/)
```

I would use `.split()` as a cursor.

```js
let txt = 
`My Name is 
Joe
My Age is 
25
My phone is
Nokia`,

age = txt.split(/Age.+/)[1].match(/.+/)[0]

console.log(age)
```

Split the text content at the line that contains `Age` and match the next line.